# SQLite3 Error Unable to Open Database File

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite

I have previously researched this on every site and SO question possible, but I am getting SQLite3 Error Unable to Open Database File when my daemon application tries to open the database I am creating. From my research I have seen to make sure the folder the database is created in has the correct permissions. The daemon process is running as root, the folder has permissions for root:root of 700, and I have logged the path to make sure it was correct and it is. Below is my code.

```
#include
<sqlite3.h>
  .... 
bool initializeDB()
{
  wstring path = L"/opt/McAfee/myproduct/resource/product.db";
  sqlite3* db;
  if(sqlite3_open16((void*)path.c_str(), &db) != SQLITE_OK)
  {
    wstringstream ss;
    ss<<L "Could not open db '"<<path<< '. Error: "<<sqlite3_errmsg(db);
    LogMsg(false, ss.str().c_str());
    sqlite3_close_v2();
    return false;
  }

  // Create table statements

  sqlite3_close_v2(db);
  return true;
}
```

I have tried doing a chmod 777 to the directory just to get it to work and I get the same error. I have also changed the path to /tmp/product.db and that also fails with the same error. The only thing that works is if I just have `wstring path = L"product.db"`, but I cannot find the .db file anywhere on the system, even after running 'find / -name "product.db" '.

Comment: Try using 8-bit strings instead of wide strings. Your path doesn't have unicode characters anyway.

Comment: I'll try it to see, but the reason for this is unicode characters in the data I'm saving later on. From sqlite documentation:

The default encoding will be UTF-8 for databases created using sqlite3_open() or sqlite3_open_v2(). The default encoding for databases created using sqlite3_open16() will be UTF-16 in the native byte order.

Comment: Okay, so your suggestion does work properly. Thanks @ColonelThirtyTwo !

Comment: I'm not too familiar with C++; make sure that `path.c_str` doesn't convert from utf-16 to 8 (from looking at the docs, it doesn't, but idk). I'm pretty sure you can set the encoding of the DB right after you open it, if you need UTF-16.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code from the above to below fixes the problem as per @Colonel Thirty Two. I'm still researching why neither sqlite3_open16(), sqlite3_open_v2(), or sqlite_close_v2() do not work on CentOS though. The latter resulting in an unrecoverable error stopping the process.

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
  .... 
bool initializeDB()
{
  string path = "/opt/McAfee/myproduct/resource/product.db";
  sqlite3* db;
  if(sqlite3_open(path.c_str(), &db) != SQLITE_OK)
  {
    LogMsg(false, L"Could not open db.");
    sqlite3_close();
    return false;
  }

  // Create table statements

  sqlite3_close(db);
  return true;
}
```